# debounce the first function call in lodash/debounce

Tags: javascript, lodash

what I'm looking for is pretty simple, but I've been stuck on it for a while :
I've been using the debounce function of lodash, in order to implement a search as you type feature.
Basically, when you type something in the search bar, the website will wait 500ms after the last keyboard input, before triggering the search.

The thing is that the very first call isn't debounced, since debounce will wait for the 2nd call in order to introduce a delay.

Right now I've configured it with the options `{ trailing: true, leading: false }`, but I can't figure out how to configure it for the first function call to be debounced.

```
const DebouncedSearchBox = ({ currentRefinement, refine }) => {
  const debouncedSearch = debounce(
    e => {
      refine(e.target.value);
      if (!e.target.value.length) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Pagination-list")
          ? Array.from(
              document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Pagination-list")
            ).forEach(function(element) {
              element.classList.add("hidden");
            })
          : null;
        document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Stats-text")
          ? Array.from(
              document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Stats-text")
            ).forEach(function(element) {
              element.classList.add("hidden");
            })
          : null;
      } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Pagination-list")
          ? Array.from(
              document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Pagination-list")
            ).forEach(function(element) {
              element.classList.remove("hidden");
            })
          : null;
        document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Stats-text")
          ? Array.from(
              document.getElementsByClassName("ais-Stats-text")
            ).forEach(function(element) {
              element.classList.remove("hidden");
            })
          : null;
      }
      document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")
        ? Array.from(
            document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")
          ).forEach(function(element) {
            element.classList.remove("loading");
          })
        : null;
    },
    500,
    { trailing: true, leading: false }
  );

  const onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log("on change" + e.target.value);
    document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")
      ? Array.from(
          document.getElementsByClassName("search_results")
        ).forEach(function(element) {
          element.classList.add("loading");
        })
      : null;
    debouncedSearch(e);
  };

  return (
    <input
      defaultValue={currentRefinement}
      onChange={onChange}
      aria-label="recherche"
      className="ais-SearchBox-input"
      autoFocus
      onFocus={e => {
        let val = e.target.value;
        e.target.value = "";
        e.target.value = val;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @DerekBrown sure

Answer (score 2):

For a standalone `debouncing` function you can add a 3rd parameter for an immediate boolean to verify that the function should execute immediately on the leading edge AND THEN wait.

**e.g.:**

```
/**
* debounce
* @type {Function}
*
* @param {Function} cb
* @param {Number} wait
* @param {Boolean} immediate
*
* @return {Function} debounced function
*/

const debounce = (cb, wait, immediate) => {
  let timeoutId;

  return () => {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;

    if (immediate) {
      cb();
    }

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => cb.apply(context, args), wait);
  }
}
```

For your current implementation, perhaps toggling the `{ leading: false}` flag to `true` should do the trick to trigger the leading edge.

Comment: hey thanks for answering! Actually I just found out I couldn't solve this problem for UX reasons that are too long to expose here. So I've changed my interface and it works better now.